# redirect location.replace does not work in button click event listener Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, button, addeventlistener

it's been an entire day I'm looking for a solution, so please answer if you know why the redirect dose not work?! I test all the methods of object location also I tried window.location methods but all are useless for me!

```html
<script>
    document.getElementById("doneButton").addEventListener("click", myfunction);
    function myfunction(){location.replace('/index.php');}
</script>
<form id="myForm" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);? "method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="formDiv">
<div id="printableArea">
<p> hello </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="printButton" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" >
<input type="submit" id="doneButton" value="Done" >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The JS tells the browser to navigate to `/index.php` then the form submission overrides it and navigates to `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?`

Comment: Use a link and not a submit button and not JavaScript.

Comment: The code shown is also indicating an error because the `#doneButton` element can't be found before it exists.  It seems there are a couple of issues here.